# What the url code can be write in the view file to call the function in Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: JSON.parse(json_events),
            //events: [{"id":"14","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-24T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":false}],
            utc: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, 
            slotDuration: '00:30:00',
            eventReceive: function(event){
                var title = event.title;
                var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'process.php',
                    data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        event.id = response.eventid;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.responseText);

                    }
                });
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                console.log(event);
            },
```

This is the code that i found online about, i dont understand abou the url part .Because i am using the Laravel, i not sure what to write in the url part.
I have create a controller and model, just not sure how to pass the data into in and store in database.

This is the `process.php` can this transform into controller and model?

```
$type = $_POST['type'];

if($type == 'new')
{
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'].'+'.$_POST['zone'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO calendar(`title`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `allDay`) VALUES('$title','$startdate','$startdate','false')");
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','eventid'=>$lastid));
}

if($type == 'changetitle')
{
    $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE calendar SET title='$title' where id='$eventid'");
    if($update)
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed'));
}

if($type == 'resetdate')
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $startdate = $_POST['start'];
    $enddate = $_POST['end'];
    $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
    $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE calendar SET title='$title', startdate = '$startdate', enddate = '$enddate' where id='$eventid'");
    if($update)
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed'));
}

if($type == 'remove')
{
    $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
    $delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM calendar where id='$eventid'");
    if($delete)
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed'));
}

if($type == 'fetch')
{
    $events = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar");
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    $e = array();
    $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
    $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
    $e['start'] = $fetch['startdate'];
    $e['end'] = $fetch['enddate'];

    $allday = ($fetch['allDay'] == "true") ? true : false;
    $e['allDay'] = $allday;

    array_push($events, $e);
    }
    echo json_encode($events);
}


?>
```

Comment: `url: 'process.php',` it must be path without website name.

Comment: This one is another example from a file, so i wonder what should put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the my logic for Laravel.

**routes.php**

```
     Route::get('/', function() {
                return View::make('hello');
        });

        Route::get('calender', 'CalendarController@showEvent');
        Route::post('calendar/add', 'CalendarController@postAdd');
```

Controller : 
**CalendarController.php**

```
    class CalendarController extends BaseController {

        function showEvent() {
            return View::make('display_event');
        }

        function postAdd() {
            echo json_encode($_POST);
        }

    }
```

View Script: **display_event.php**
Download View : [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1gDv6V6LYMpUHJ5Umo0ZGtyQVk/view?usp=sharing)

Please compare html with 
http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.4.1/ajaxversion/#ajax/calendar.html (Ajax calender view)

View load by ajax : 
http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.4.1/ajaxversion/ajax/calendar.html

Hope this will work for You.

Comment: Yours one is very nice, but how could you add the event into the database, i know that is link, but how you control in the ajax and the database?

Comment: Hi Yes second link will not work because in 1st link you can see calendar is loading from ajax request. so in first page you can't see html of calendar.

I had handle variables in CalendarController.
now you need to just pass that values to database. simple :-)

Comment: Bro, if i use the display_event.php and the controller and the router.php. Then no need for the model?

Comment: Yes We can do that way.  but if we are using MVC this is not a good way.
But we can !!

Comment: I know your spirit, maybe you can help me look at it. I not sure am i doing that correct or not.. Sudden, my calendar not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it

```
 Url :"<?php echo action('YourController@getIndex');?>",
```

You can Replace getIndex to any method you

Comment: But what should i put on the controller?

Comment: Just Simple Form Like you are posting values on that controller.
and you need to return json like
{"id":"14","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-24T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":false}

Comment: Can give some example, like if i want to pass the title and id from the ajax into it? How controller and model handle?

Comment: http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.4.1/ajaxversion/#ajax/calendar.html

Example without ajax. but you can get idea with javascript.

Comment: If you can provide me flow chart i can understand what you need.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Arios509/calendar/ This is my file, that i change on the part you teach me. But it come out error, so i wonder what is the main problem.  This is my draft flowchart http://imgur.com/gallery/9qSNia1/new

Comment: Bro, got one css that effect my layout, which is smartadmin-production.min.css , it will turn my navigation bar become strange and the logout button cant use.. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes Smartadmin-production.min.css will be affect on following tags
ul / li / buttons / etc. 
But it will work fine with bootstrap.

Comment: Erm, i came out with the layout already, but the problem is `title = title.length === 0 ? "Untitled Event" : title;` this code is about add into the database right? The last title mean the name in the database?

Comment: Any way to  make the website can look nicely without those creepy layouts?